# Query does not output time

Tags: php, datetime

I cannot get the

```
$result = DatabaseHandler::query($query);
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $this->mTaskDateCreated[] = $row;
            }
```

to output the time once the user has submitted the form. I'm not sure whereabouts exactly the problems lies as the other two `$result` work as they return the text entered into the field. 
How can I get the `$result` to return the value of the `datetime`?

```
<?php
    class ProjectBody {
        public $mTasks = array();
        public $mTaskName = array();
        public $mTaskDateCreated = array();

        public function __construct() {


            if(isset($_POST['task_name']) && isset($_POST['task'])) {
                $task_name = DatabaseHandler::escape($_POST['task_name']);
                $task = DatabaseHandler::escape($_POST['task']);

                $query = "INSERT INTO `project` (name, task, date_created) VALUES ('$task_name', '$task', NOW())";
                $result = DatabaseHandler::query($query);
            }

            $query = "SELECT * FROM `project` ORDER BY `id` DESC";
            $result = DatabaseHandler::query($query);


            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $this->mTaskName[] = $row;
            }
            $result = DatabaseHandler::query($query);

            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
              $this->mTasks[] = $row;  
            }
            $result = DatabaseHandler::query($query);

            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $this->mTaskDateCreated[] = $row;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Thanks.